# Can't click on stack trace links in Android Studio anymore

Tags: flutter, android-studio, logging, mobile

After a recent update for Flutter I found that in Android Studio the package links in stack traces are no longer clickable.
This is not the case with Visual Studio as the links *are* clickable

Has anyone come across this issue and does anyone know how to fix it?

I'm not a fan of Visual Studio for various usability reasons.

[image: Links no longer clickable]

Comment: Is this flutter web? I think it's the difference between mobile and web

Comment: it's a Flutter mobile project. It was allowing me to click on the links before to go to the line of code the stack trace was on. It still does if I open the project in Visual Studio

Comment: i have this issue too. i think new android studio version has this issue?
do you found any workaround?

Comment: Too many bugs with IntelliJ plugin. I've switched to VS Code.

Comment: do you found any workaround?

Comment: Seems it was a bug in the IDE itself that they eventually fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by upgrading android studio dart plugin to version `213.7371`

Comment: Yeah, it seems that they realised it was a bug and fixed it in a later update.